# How can I join 2 or more mapData in my highmaps?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I want to plot Asia-Pacific (Asia and Africa), how can I achieve this?

```
    series: [{
        data: data,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/asia'],
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Random data',
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to just join two maps you mentioned, because they have different base coordinates/properties. You would end up with two overlapping maps - [demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/xsr33xqy/), [demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/xsr33xqy/1/).

You could use bigger map - with more than you need (e.g. continents world map). Next don't provide data for areas you do not want to have and set [`allAreas`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#series<map>.allAreas) to false.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8wsezjqy/

Another option is to create a custom map as explained in [the Docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-maps).